Seek for a particular header design
This is a follow-up to the question I raised 2 days ago.
My latex template is \documentclass{book}. What can I do to make the headers of all pages (no matter of even or odd) centered to show the section title?
The figure below is what I want to have (mainly the red circles)

But what I got is by default from the book template, see figure below  where one can see

the headers are not centered;
pages from odd and even show different header content.


EDIT: See Addition below.
Use fancyhdr.

% Page headers and footers.

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

If you don't want the line under the headers, add
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


Addition:
To get Title Caps, add the following:
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Addlcwords{the is a an} % add your own words not to be capitalised
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~\titlecap{#1}}}

See the titlecaps documentation for more info.
To get the header in bold, change the \fancyhead line to
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\rightmark}}



Thank you so much. I just noticed that I also need the header to be "title case". Could you provide any update to solve it?

See the addition at the end of my answer. You could also write the titles in Title Caps yourself, then you can remove the call to titlecap and the \usepackage{titlecaps} of course.

Thank you for the detailed answer!
